# Getting error as 0 nodes out of 2 have registered : cluster may be unhealthy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, prisma, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm getting some issue when creating google composer environment it says like

error waiting for creating environment Error code 4, message: composer backend time out. Got error "polled operation status: DONE: All cluster resources were brought up, but only 0 nodes out of 2 have registered: Cluster may be unhealthy," during CP_GKE_CLUSTER_CREATING.

if anybody have any idea about it please help on it

NOTE: trying the kms configuration in it and image version is composer-2.4.0-airflow-2.5.3 and trying to create using terraform

Answer (score 0):

we miss some information to better troubleshoot the error:

- can you look at the GKE and the Composer logs and share any details related to the error?

It seems the nodes are failing to communicate to the control plane, so most likley some firewall rules missing.

Generally speaking, you might want to double-check the following:

- SA used to create the Composer cluster has enough permissions to interact with the network services
- given you are using Terraform, make sure all the dependent resources are created before proceeding with the Composer creation (network, subnetwork with secondary ranges, firewall, service account)

The GKE cluster takes anything between 10-20minutes to be up&running, for Composer to then install all the requirement it has.

I might suggest you to follow the docs here (they now added the Terraform code too):

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/create-environments#terraform

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/terraform-create-environments

Answer (score 0):

Check if the subnet has a Google private access enabled. Most of the time we miss to enable it